# Increase SO font size via Javascript doesn’t work on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, css, safari, font-size

So, I've been using this little bit of Javascript (as a bookmark) to increase the font size of various websites I visit on my iPhone's Safari browser (zooming in leads to too much scrolling from side to side).

http://www.everythingicafe.com/forum/iphone-software/increase-font-size-in-safari-without-zooming-9511.html

```
javascript:for(i=0;i<document.getElementsByTagName ('*')
.length;i++)void(document.getElementsByTagName('*' )
[i].style.fontSize='18pt');
```

However, this doesn't work on any of the StackOverflow sites. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Poking thru the CSS in FireBug doesn't give me many clues except for a font-size: 100% that is in the p tag.

I tried changing fontSize='115%'); and it changed some of the text but not the question/answer body (the most important stuff!)

Comment: What if you do fontSize='115% !important'

Comment: As I said on meta: Your JavaScript works well with SO in my Firefox.

Comment: balpha: Doesn't work on Safari :D Is FireFox even available on the iPhone??

Comment: Not that I know of; I'm talking desktop. I was uttering suprise more than anything, because if I understand correctly, it works everywhere *except* on SO. Does it work on desktop Safari?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Overflow uses relative font sizes for everything.

Here is a simple fix to adjust the font size for the entire document:

```
javascript:void(document.body.style.fontSize = '16pt');
```